# Facing RDS db connection issue in codeigniter 3.x when deploying on server

Tags: codeigniter-3, ubuntu-16.04

Facing issue in codeigniter 3.x when trying to connect RDS on amazon
i have installed PHP Version 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 with mysql

```
$db['develop'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'username' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
//  'char_set' => 'utf8',
//  'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'char_set' => 'utf8mb4',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
```

> Not able to connect db
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
>   Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>   Line Number: 201

And when try to connect same db from localhost its working fine. I am using amazon ubuntu 16.04 with RDS. Please suggest

Comment: Same issue happen with me in Symfony; Working fine in localhost(ubuntu 14.04) but getting 'Connection time out' error in AWS EC2 (ubuntu 16.04) server in AWS RDS.